# Matlab GUI - Trouble updating handles using an update function

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

I am not sure if I'm going about this the right way, but I want to have a function that when called, essentially resets 4 plots. I store the plots as `handles.distplot1`, `handles.distplot2` and so on in hopes of having a drop down to select which plot is shown on the axis. I will need reset these plots after a few different events, so naturally I want to toss them in a function and avoid code redundancy. I hope a function like

```
function setupDistPlots(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % filler data for surfc
    x = [1 2];
    z = zeros(2);
    % setup blank plots for funtion to work with
    a = figure(1); set(a, 'Visible', 'off')
    handles.distplot1 = surfc(x, x, z);
    b = figure(2); set(b, 'Visible', 'off');
    handles.distplot2 = bar(NaN);
    c = figure(3); set(c, 'Visible', 'off')
    handles.distplot3 = surfc(x, x, z);
    d = figure(4); set(d, 'Visible', 'off')
    handles.distplot4 = bar(NaN);
    guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Which I believe should work as intended, but I have no idea how to call it. In the opening function I try `setupDistPlots(hObject, eventdata, handles)` but receive the following error when I try to access `handles.distplot1` later on:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'distplot1'.

Error in tabbedGUI>distanceToggle_Callback (line 212)
                distribution(hObject,
                handles.distplot1, ...

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in tabbedGUI (line 45)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)tabbedGUI('distanceToggle_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

edit: Also please point out everything I could improve. Everything I do in Matlab feels hackish like there must be a better way.

edit2: The problem with the opening function was calling `setupDistPlots` before the `guidata(hObject, handles)` call of the opening function. However now when when I call `setupDistPlots' again on a button press I get the following error:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.primitive.Data/set
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in andrewDistribution (line 45)
    set(hplot1, 'xData', x1, 'yData', y1, 'zData', zeros(length(x1)))

Error in tabbedGUI>distanceToggle_Callback (line 200)
                distribution(hObject, handles.distplot1, ...

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in tabbedGUI (line 45)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)tabbedGUI('distanceToggle_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Comment: Are you triggering that callback by clicking on something or is MATLAB trying to call that callback when loading the GUI?

Comment: Where in the opening function did you place that line? If it's before the existing `guidata(hObject, handles);` line then your changes will be overwritten by the default GUIDE handles. Also, It's `handles`, not `handle`.

Comment: The error is when I click on a button and the callback tries to access `handles.distplot1`. `setupDistPlots` is run in the opening function but does not seem to update the handles. The error is not until I click a certain button

Comment: @excaza I was calling it before the existing `guidata(hObject, handles)` however I just threw `handles` at the end of `setupDistPlots()` and it doesn't look like there are entires for `distplot1`, `displot2`, etc... but there is a `figure1` entry. I feel like I am going about this the entirely wrong way, but I have no other idea on how to store plots in a matlab gui

Comment: `setupDistPlots` needs to go *after* the `guidata` call, or you need to output `handles` from `setupDistPlots`.

Comment: @excaza I was wrong in that last comment. I was thinking the output was in alphabetical order. The plots exist in `handles` at the end of `setupDistPlots`, but calling `handles` immediately after calling `setupDistPlots` they are not present. Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: @excaza That appears to have solved my problem. If you write that as a solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: Regarding your edit: closing a figure window will delete them from memory. Attempting to reference it after this will throw the error you receive.

Comment: Does setting the visibility to False act the same as closing the window? What is the best way to keep track of multiple plots but only display 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your initial attempt looked like this:

```
% --- Executes just before testgui is made visible.
function testgui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% Choose default command line output for testgui
handles.output = hObject;

setupDistPlots(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

As talked to in the comments, your changes to the `handles` structure saved to the GUI by `setupDistPlots` using [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) are being overwritten by the GUIDE's subsequent `guidata` call. The short answer is to put `setupDistPlots` *after* `guidata` to make everything function as written.

---

Now the longer answer. I'm going to guess that you're familiar mostly working with [MATLAB scripts rather than MATLAB functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html). Where scripts share a base workspace, [functions each have their own separate workspace in memory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html). As written there is no way for your `OpeningFcn` to know that you have changed the `handles` structure, so it happily overwrites your changes using the value of `handles` that was passed to `setupDistPlots`. To get around this, you need to include some way for the `OpeningFcn` to know that you have made changes.

One approach is to [specify an output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) for `setupDistPlots`:

```
function handles = setupDistPlots(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % filler data for surfc
    x = [1 2];
    z = zeros(2);
    % setup blank plots for funtion to work with
    a = figure(1); set(a, 'Visible', 'off')
    handles.distplot1 = surfc(x, x, z);
    b = figure(2); set(b, 'Visible', 'off');
    handles.distplot2 = bar(NaN);
    c = figure(3); set(c, 'Visible', 'off')
    handles.distplot3 = surfc(x, x, z);
    d = figure(4); set(d, 'Visible', 'off')
    handles.distplot4 = bar(NaN);
```

Placing `setupDistPlots` before the `guidata` call in your GUIDE code:

```
% --- Executes just before testgui is made visible.
function testgui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% Choose default command line output for testgui
handles.output = hObject;

handles = setupDistPlots(hObject, eventdata, handles);

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm more used to dealing with function. I'm newer to Matlab and have no idea how `guidata` worked. I assumed it updated a global or something like that, but what you said makes perfect sense. I constantly forget `handles` is passed as an argument. I feel like an idiot. I also made an edit to my question. I'll see if these suggestions help.